# Deploy PHP application to webroot using Eclipse PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse-pdt

Is it possible to have a PHP project located in a directory, say -
mydir/development/php/myproject

and then when you click Run/Debug in Eclipse it gets automatically deployed to the apache /www webroot directory?

Comment: If you map the webdirectory onto your project directory, you don't need to build + deploy even. That is probably most straight forward in your case. I do that for example with wordpress development.

Comment: Which webserver are you using? If apache, checkout the virtual host and/or the alias directive.